# Implement specific method in generic class

Tags: c++, templates, generics, types, template-specialization

I've got a questions, searched for some time on the internet but nothing good came out.

I have a generic class `Image2D` for a 2D picture:

```
template <typename TValue>
class Image2D 
{
    public:
    typedef Image2D<TValue>    Self;      // le type de *this
    typedef TValue             Value;     // le type pour la valeur des pixels
    typedef std::vector<Value> Container; // le type pour stocker les valeurs des pixels de l'image.

    Image2D( int w, int h, Value g = Value() )
        : m_width(w), m_height(h), m_data(Container(w * h, g)) { }

    struct Iterator : public Container::iterator 
    {
        Iterator( Self & image, int x, int y ) 
        : Container::iterator( image.m_data.begin() + image.index( x, y ) ) { }
    };
    Iterator begin() 
    { 
        return start( 0, 0 );
    }
    Iterator end()   
    { 
        return start( 0, h() ); 
    }
    Iterator start( int x, int y ) 
    { 
        return Iterator( *this, x, y ); 
    }
...
};
```

It enables me to chose specific types for the pixels of the picture, like for example `unsigned char` or `Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)` when I instantiate that generic class.

I need to add a method to that class, where the implementation may differ for certain types :

```
template <typename TValue>
class Image2D
{
...

    template <typename Color>
    void sepiaFilter()
    {
        for(Iterator it = this -> begin(), itE = this -> end(); it != itE; ++it)
        {
            Color oldColor = *it;

            Color newColor = oldColor;

            newColor.red = std::min((oldColor.red * .393) + (oldColor.green * .769) + (oldColor.blue * .189), 255.0);
            newColor.green = std::min((oldColor.red * .349) + (oldColor.green * .686) + (oldColor.blue * .168), 255.0);
            newColor.blue = std::min((oldColor.red * .272) + (oldColor.green * .534) + (oldColor.blue * .131), 255.0);

            *it = newColor;
        }
    }
...
};
```

The same would apply for `unsigned char`, but the core of the method should not be the same.

The problem is that I don't know how to do specialize the generic function for specific types.  I tried to create this :

```
template<>
class Image2D<Color> 
{
    template <typename Color>
    void sepiaFilter()
    {
        for(Iterator it = this -> begin(), itE = this -> end(); it != itE; ++it)
        {
            Color oldColor = *it;

            Color newColor = oldColor;

            newColor.red = std::min((oldColor.red * .393) + (oldColor.green * .769) + (oldColor.blue * .189), 255.0);
            newColor.green = std::min((oldColor.red * .349) + (oldColor.green * .686) + (oldColor.blue * .168), 255.0);
            newColor.blue = std::min((oldColor.red * .272) + (oldColor.green * .534) + (oldColor.blue * .131), 255.0);

            *it = newColor;
        }
    }
}
```

And create another specific class of Image2D. But doing that requires that the iterator must be re-implemented in that specialized class; so I can't use the generic class' iterator.

So none of those solutions works so I'm asking for help .. Heeeeelp!

How could I do what I want?

Comment: I would recommend writing sepiaFilter as a standalone function template, rather than a member. You can then easily overload it for specific cases.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly which cases of `Image2D<TValue>::sepiaFilter<Color>(Image2D)` you want to specialize.  When `TValue` and `Color` are the same type? When one or both of them is `unsigned char`?

Comment: Also, your `sepiaFilter` function appears not to use `this`. So maybe it shouldn't have a separate `Image2D` argument, or it should be `static`, or it should be a non-member as n.m. suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then there are a few routes you could take. The one which I think you want is template specialization. For this, you want to modify the generic class to include the function you want to specialize:

```
template <typename TValue>
class Image2D{
    //your original code here
    void sepiaFilter(Image2D<Value> img){}
};
```

Notice that I didn't give the function a body. Right now it doesn't do anything. Now we specialize the function:

```
template<>
void Image2D<Color>::sepiaFilter(Image2D<Color> img){
    //body of your function here
}
```

And that's it! `Image2D<Color>` now has specially defined behavior.

Also, this wasn't part of your question, but a word to the wise on your footprint for that function. I would recommend instead using

```
//code before function definition
static void sepiaFilter(Image2D<Value>& img){
    //modify member values of img by reference
}
//code after function definition
```

`static` is added because the function doesn't modify member values of its own object. And the ampersand makes it passed by reference, otherwise any changes you make to `img` would vanish when you're done. Alternatively, you could do this:

```
//code before function definition
void sepiaFilter(){
    //modify member values of this
}
//code after function definition
```

In this case, you would want to be modifying its own members rather than members of something passed

At any rate, I hope this answered your question, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help! Bronicki's solution is working.
After doing what he said using

```
void sepiaFilter() { ... }
```

was a good solution.

I called it with

```
img.sepiaFilter();
```

in the main method, img being an Image2D instance.